# How to get progress bar with tqdm in a for loop over directory with directories inside?

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm tring to get a progress bar of a directory with multiple folders inside as follows:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath("my_folder/")) :
    for file in tqdm(files):
        if file.endswith(".ext"):
```

I have a folder with folders inside (folder_A, folder_B, folder_C) and files on each folder, it's possible with tqdm to get a overall progress bar?